# Convolutional Neural Network with Non-Existent Loss and Accuracy of 0

Tags: python, keras, classification, conv-neural-network

I am attempting to train a simple convolutional neural network shown below.

```
model= Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(32, 3, padding='same', input_shape=(700,7))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv1D(32,3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D())
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile('adam', 'binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I fit it using 100 epochs and a validation training split 0.2 on input data shaped [1000L, 700L, 7L]. Every single one of my epochs displaed the following:

```
loss: nan - acc:0.0000e+00 - val_loss: nan - val_acc: 0.0000e+00
```

So my question is, what went wrong and how do I fix it? Is the problem with the network or how my data is being inputed and fitted to the model?

Comment: Consider showing your training routine

Comment: Try a lower learning rate

Comment: Add an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @EmanueleGiona my training routine looked something like                                                                                                         `model.fit(x=X_train, y=Y_train, epochs=100, validation_split=.2)`